# Ubuntu freezes during boot

Tags: 14.04, boot

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 on a Acer E17 laptop. From one to another the computer seems to freeze during the boot sequence. It boots to grub without an issue, but when I select Ubuntu it seems to freeze on a black screen. No indication as to what it's doing or any error code. Normally it would display the word Ubuntu with 5 dots beneath it that change from white to red.

If I boot the recovery boot (of the same kernel) and in recovery immediately hit resume it boots normally and I can login.

I already tried to downgrade some recent updates using synaptic, but that did not help. The next thing I tried is to try to create some boot logs with bootlogd, but `/var/log/boot.log` remains empty. Does anyone have an idea where to go next?

Edit: after a couple of days `/var/log/boot.log` and `/var/log/boot` have some information, but no errors of any kind.

`cat /var/log/boot` produces this output: http://pastebin.com/FEjBveEG

`cat /var/log/boot.log` produces this output: http://pastebin.com/iycLg0p0
(formatting is off, no idea why, it isn't in the output)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu actually waits for all the essential drivers and environment application to load before log you in. In my case, I intended to overwrite the default (lightdm unity) with gnome-shell, bit it failed and the boot sequence was waiting infinitely for it to run. So I need to rollback my changes but there isn't much i can do since I cant actually get myself to terminal (the "shift" + boot didn't work).

Here's what I did to resolve the issue:

1. Plugged in my usb bootable ubuntu and ran trial version.
2. Browsed through the bootdrive and edited `/etc/X11/default-display-manager`.
3. It didn't allow me to write so I assigned writable permission to it
   with `sudo chmod 777 /etc/X11/ -R`.
4. Then I changed the line  `/usr/sbin/gdm`  to `/usr/sbin/lightdm` and the rebooted. By doing this I rolled back the changed from gnome-shell to lightdm, and I saved myself from reinstalling the system.

Comment: you don't need to change the permissions in step 3 -- simply use `sudo` with your editor to edit the file. this will avoid any future problems caused by incorrect permissions.

Comment: yea ,i would have but i dont know why,the changes i made with sudo nano never been updated..so i just went to more obvious way of doing it.