# Ubuntu 16.10 freezes at startup

Tags: grub2, freeze, 16.10

Sometimes my computer can not start Ubuntu 16.10 but I had this too with Ubuntu 16.04.
The specifications and versions are below.

There are two ways how it freezes:

1. In the grub bootloader it freezes when I press a arrow key.
2. If I wait the 30 secs it freezes with a black screen without showing a logo or something else. Before the black screen the num, caps and scroll lock lights lights up for maybe a second.

Now I could start after unplugging my computer from power.
But there is no problem starting the PC with Windows (7 and 10) for months.

I think there is a problem with `grub` on my PC because I have no problems if it could start.

Please help me, I would like to use Ubuntu and not Windows again ...

---

grub-install (GRUB) 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu11
Kernel: 4.8.0-27-generic
Motherboard: Asus Maximus Hero VIII
CPU: i7-6700
Legacy mode
fully updated system

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)  
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)  
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)  
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)  
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Root Port #17 (rev f1)  
00:1b.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Root Port #19 (rev f1)  
00:1b.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Root Port #20 (rev f1)  
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)  
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)  
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)  
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)  
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)  
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)  
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V (rev 31)  
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tobago PRO [Radeon R7 360 / R9 360 OEM] (rev 81)  
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tobago HDMI Audio [Radeon R7 360 / R9 360 OEM]  
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)  
04:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)  
05:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
```

Boot info:

```
[  OK  ] Found device Hitachi_HDS5C3020BLE630 1.  
         Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/9e8d153a-5944-4dcf-bc56-ab4edcb0a8e1...  
[  OK  ] Started File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/9e8d153a-5944-4dcf-bc56-ab4edcb0a8e1.  
         Mounting /data/HDD0...  
[  OK  ] Mounted /data/HDD0.  
[  OK  ] Reached target Local File Systems.  
         Starting Set console font and keymap...  
         Starting AppArmor initialization...  
         Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...  
         Starting Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up...  
         Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...  
         Starting Run snappy firstboot setup...  
[  OK  ] Started Set console font and keymap.  
[  OK  ] Started Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up.  
         Starting Nameserver information manager...  
[  OK  ] Started Nameserver information manager.  
[  OK  ] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.  
[  OK  ] Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.  
         Starting Network Time Synchronization...  
         Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...  
[  OK  ] Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.  
[  OK  ] Started Run snappy firstboot setup.  
[  OK  ] Started AppArmor initialization.  
         Starting Raise network interfaces...  
[  OK  ] Started Network Time Synchronization.  
[  OK  ] Reached target System Initialization.  
         Starting Socket activation for snappy daemon.  
[  OK  ] Listening on UUID daemon activation socket.  
[  OK  ] Listening on ACPID Listen Socket.  
[  OK  ] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.  
[  OK  ] Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.  
[  OK  ] Started ACPI Events Check.  
[  OK  ] Started CUPS Scheduler.  
[  OK  ] Reached target Paths.  
[  OK  ] Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.  
[  OK  ] Listening on CUPS Scheduler.  
[  OK  ] Reached target System Time Synchronized.  
[  OK  ] Started Timer to automatically refresh installed snaps.  
[  OK  ] Started Daily apt activities.  
[  OK  ] Reached target Timers.  
[  OK  ] Listening on Socket activation for snappy daemon.  
[  OK  ] Reached target Sockets.  
[  OK  ] Reached target Basic System.  
[  OK  ] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.  
         Starting Daily apt activities...  
         Starting Modem Manager...  
         Starting Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes...  
[  OK  ] Started crash report submission daemon.  
         Starting System Logging Service...  
[  OK  ] Started Snappy daemon.  
[  OK  ] Started CUPS Scheduler.  
         Starting Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down...  
         Starting Network Manager...  
         Starting Initialize hardware monitoring sensors...  
         Starting Thermal Daemon Service...  
[  OK  ] Started Cgroup management daemon.  
[  OK  ] Started Regular background program processing daemon.  
[  OK  ] Started ACPI event daemon.  
         Starting LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems...  
         Starting LSB: Load kernel modules needed to enable cpufreq scaling...  
         Starting Login Service...  
[  OK  ] Started Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor.  
         Starting Accounts Service...  
[  OK  ] Started Run anacron jobs.  
         Starting LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...  
         Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...  
         Starting Run Click system-level hooks...  
         Starting LSB: automatic crash report generation...  
         Starting LSB: Speech Dispatcher...  
         Starting Save/Restore Sound Card State...  
[  OK  ] Started Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down.  
[  OK  ] Started Initialize hardware monitoring sensors.  
[  OK  ] Started Save/Restore Sound Card State.  
[  OK  ] Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.  
[  OK  ] Started Thermal Daemon Service.  
[  OK  ] Started Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.  
[  OK  ] Started System Logging Service.  
[  OK  ] Started Raise network interfaces.  
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Speech Dispatcher.  
[  OK  ] Started Login Service.  
         Starting Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks...  
[  OK  ] Started Make remote CUPS printers available locally.  
[  OK  ] Started LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems.  
[  OK  ] Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.  
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Load kernel modules needed to enable cpufreq scaling.  
         Starting LSB: set CPUFreq kernel parameters...  
[  OK  ] Started LSB: set CPUFreq kernel parameters.  
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.  
[  OK  ] Started Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks.  
[  OK  ] Started Accounts Service.  
[  OK  ] Started Network Manager.  
[  OK  ] Reached target Network.  
         Starting OpenVPN service...  
         Starting Network Name Resolution...  
         Starting Permit User Sessions...  
         Starting Network Manager Wait Online...  
[  OK  ] Started OpenVPN service.  
[  OK  ] Started Permit User Sessions.  
         Starting Light Display Manager...  
         Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...  
         Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...  
[  OK  ] Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.  
[  OK  ] Started Modem Manager.  
         Starting Hostname Service...
```

Comment: There are 4 routes I would try here: a) pulling your AMD graphics card and checking for issues, b) reinstall, c) http://askubuntu.com/questions/617572/ubuntu-freezes-during-boot, d) editing your question with the the results of `/var/log/boot.log`.

Comment: The "the grub bootloader it freezes when I press a arrow key" problem is probably caused if you run with a wireless keyboard... ie: Logitech

Comment: For the last two weeks I wasn able to reproduce the issue. I have a wired keybord

Comment: Yesterday I had the issue again. I unplugged every USB-Device and restarted without success. So i have to test the Hardware inside the PC.

Comment: Tested with ubuntu 16.04.2, 15.04, Debian stable (8.7.1) & test and different USB-devices (and without). The Hardware is working perfect with Windows and Linux (if it starts).
Is it possible that grub has a Problem with the Mainboard (for example the SATA-Controler on the ASUS Hero VIII)?
I test it with LILO.