# Boot kind of freezing in 18.04, but not really

Tags: boot, 18.04

My Ubuntu won't start.

While booting up, it comes up with a list of things its doing (which I do not normally see). Everything says "OK" next to it which makes me think everything is OK. However, after it displays the following:

`Started dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd.ally.ed before the ppp link was shut down...`

it just stays there. Everything still says OK but it is clearly not OK as I never get the login screen. I've tried waiting 35 minutes, still no change.

I did some searching and found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/787373). I tried it and I do not think it helped. It did change something as now the final line says:

`Started dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd. any system changes.pp link was shut down...`

I am starting to think that this final line is being overwritten so there might be multiple statements, which is all the more confusing to a new user like myself.

As I said, it never gets past this point. However, when I press the power button Ubuntu does shut down nicely, so I know it is not frozen but I also do not see a way to use my machine.

I tried restarting with an earlier kernel but that did not help.

Do I need to reinstall my OS or is there some way to recover from this?